# How to 'quantize' a classical code?

Tags: qiskit

I have a `class` written in Python:

```
class NotAPrimePolynomialException(Exception):
    pass

class Polynomial:
    M = []

    def __init__(self, coefficients):
        self.coefficients = coefficients
        
    @staticmethod
    def unit():
        return Polynomial([1])

    @staticmethod
    def zero():
        return Polynomial([0])

    @staticmethod 
    def _add_coefficients(coeff1, coeff2):
        res = []
        i = 0
        for (b1, b2) in zip(coeff1, coeff2):
            res.append(b1 ^ b2)
            i += 1

        for j in range(i, max(len(coeff1), len(coeff2))):
            if len(coeff2) > len(coeff1):
                res.append(coeff2[j])
            else:
                res.append(coeff1[j])
        return res

    @staticmethod
    def _divide_coefficients(coeff1, coeff2):
        dividend = coeff1
        divisor = coeff2

        dividend = dividend[::-1]
        divisor = divisor[::-1]

        chunk_size = len(divisor)
        quotient = []
        chunk = [0, *dividend[:chunk_size-1]]

        for i in range(chunk_size-1, len(dividend)):
            chunk = [*chunk[1:], dividend[i]]
            if chunk[0] == 1:
                quotient.append(1)
                chunk = Polynomial._add_coefficients(chunk, divisor)
            else:
                quotient.append(0)
        return quotient[::-1], chunk[::-1]

    def modulo_reduce(self):
        return Polynomial(Polynomial._divide_coefficients(self.coefficients, Polynomial.M)[1])

    def scalar_mul(self, scalar):
        if scalar % 2 == 1:
            return self 
        return Polynomial([0])

    def is_element(self):
        return self.coefficients == [1] or any(Polynomial._divide_coefficients(self.M, self.coefficients)[1])

    def inverse(self):
        if not self.is_element():
            raise NotAPrimePolynomialException(f"{Polynomial(self.M)} is not a prime polynomial!")

        order = 2**(len(self.M)-1)-1
        res = self**(order-1)

        if res*self != Polynomial.unit():
            raise NotAPrimePolynomialException(f"{Polynomial(self.M)} is not a prime polynomial!")

        return res

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return str(self) == str(other)

    def __add__(self, other):
        temp = Polynomial(Polynomial._add_coefficients(self.coefficients, other.coefficients))
        return temp.modulo_reduce()

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        return self + other

    def __neg__(self):
        return self

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self + other

    def __isub__(self, other):
        return self + other

    def __mul__(self, other):
        coeff1 = self.coefficients
        coeff2 = other.coefficients

        def normalise(coeff1, coeff2):
            len1 = len(coeff1)
            len2 = len(coeff2)
            maxLen = max(len1, len2)

            if len1 < len2:
                for i in range(len2 - len1):
                    coeff1.append(0)
            elif len1 > len2:
                for i in range(len1 - len2):
                    coeff2.append(0)

            if maxLen % 2 != 0:
                coeff1.append(0)
                coeff2.append(0)
                maxLen += 1

            return maxLen

        def karatsuba(coeff1, coeff2):
            n = normalise(coeff1, coeff2)

            a, b = coeff1[:n//2], coeff1[n//2:]
            c, d = coeff2[:n//2], coeff2[n//2:]

            if n//2 == 1:
                ac = [a[0] * c[0]]
                bd = [b[0] * d[0]]
                mid = [(a[0]^b[0])*(c[0]^d[0])]
            else:
                ac = karatsuba(a,c)
                bd = karatsuba(b,d)
                mid = karatsuba(Polynomial._add_coefficients(a, b), Polynomial._add_coefficients(c, d))

            mid = Polynomial._add_coefficients(mid, Polynomial._add_coefficients(ac, bd))

            for i in range(n):
                bd.insert(0, 0)

            for i in range(n//2):
                mid.insert(0, 0)

            return Polynomial._add_coefficients(mid, Polynomial._add_coefficients(ac, bd))

        return Polynomial(karatsuba(coeff1, coeff2)).modulo_reduce()

    def __imul__(self, other):
        return self * other

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return self * other.inverse()

    def __pow__(self, power: int):
        temp = Polynomial(self.coefficients)
        answer = Polynomial.unit()

        while power != 0:
            if power & 1: 
                answer *= temp
                
            temp *= temp
            power >>= 1

        return answer

    def __str__(self):
        res = ""
        for i, v in enumerate(self.coefficients):
            if v == 0:
                continue

            if i == 0:
                res += f"{v} "
            elif i == 1:
                res += f"+ x "
            elif i == len(self.coefficients) - 1:
                res += f"+ x^{i}"
            else:
                res += f"+ x^{i} "
        if res == "":
            res = "0"
        if res[0] == "+":
            res = res[2:]
        return res.strip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Polynomial.M = [1,1,0,0,1]
    poly1 = Polynomial([1,1,0,1])
    poly2 = Polynomial([0,1])
    print(f"Poly1: {poly1}")
    print(f"Poly2: {poly2}")
    print(f"M: {Polynomial(Polynomial.M)}\n")

    print(f"Poly1+Poly2: {poly1+poly2}")
    print(f"Poly1*Poly2: {poly1*poly2}")
    print(f"Poly1/Poly2: {poly1/poly2}")
```

Is there a way to convert this to qiskit quantum code one-to-one? The arrays of 0 and 1 will become QuantumRegisters, and the operations will correspond to applying quantum gates on the qubits. And the whole thing would occur in a single `QuantumCircuit`.

I have tried doing this till now:

```
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumRegister, QuantumCircuit, ClassicalRegister
from qiskit.circuit.library import IGate, XGate, CXGate
from qiskit.providers.aer import AerSimulator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class QPolynomial:
    M = []
    qc = QuantumCircuit()
    sim = AerSimulator()

    def __init__(self, coeff: list[int], name='p'):
        self.name = name

        coeff = list(map(lambda x: x%2, coeff))
        for i in range(len(coeff), len(QPolynomial.M)-1):
            coeff.append(0)
        self.coeff = coeff

        QPolynomial.qc.add_register(QuantumRegister(len(QPolynomial.M)-1, name))

        for i in range(1, len(QPolynomial.M)):
            QPolynomial.qc.append(IGate(), [-i])
            if i <= len(coeff) and coeff[-i] == 1:
                QPolynomial.qc.append(XGate(), [-i])

    def _find_bit_index(self, named_index):
        ics = list(map(lambda x: x.qubits[0], QPolynomial.qc.data))
        bit_locations = list(map(lambda x: QPolynomial.qc.find_bit(x), ics))
        bit_locations = list(filter(lambda x: x.registers[0][0].name == self.name, bit_locations))
        bit_locations = list(filter(lambda x: x.registers[0][1] == named_index, bit_locations))
        if len(bit_locations) == 0:
            return -1
        return bit_locations[0].index

    def __str__(self):
        s = ""
        count = 0
        for ic in QPolynomial.qc[::-1]:
            if ic.operation.name != 'id':
                continue

            qubit = ic.qubits[0]
            bit_location = QPolynomial.qc.find_bit(qubit)
            qr = bit_location.registers[0]
            if qr[0].name != self.name:
                continue

            if count != 0:
                s += f"{qr[0].name}{qr[1]} x^{count} + "
            else:
                s += f"{qr[0].name}{qr[1]} + "
            count += 1
        return s[:-2]

    def measure_polynomial(self):
        QPolynomial.qc.add_register(ClassicalRegister(size=len(self.coeff), name='R'))
        indices = [self._find_bit_index(x) for x in range(len(self.coeff))]
        QPolynomial.qc.measure(indices, range(len(self.coeff))[::-1])

        job = QPolynomial.sim.run(QPolynomial.qc)
        return job.result().get_counts()

    @staticmethod
    def pc():
        QPolynomial.qc.draw(output='mpl')

    @staticmethod
    def add_polynomials(poly1, poly2):
        for i in range(len(QPolynomial.M)-1):
            QPolynomial.qc.append(CXGate(), [poly1._find_bit_index(i), poly2._find_bit_index(i)])

    @@staticmethod
    def _divide_polynomials(poly1, poly2):
        pass

QPolynomial.M = [1,1,0,0,1]
qpoly1 = QPolynomial([1,0,1])
qpoly2 = QPolynomial([0,1,1,1], name='q')
QPolynomial.add_polynomials(qpoly1, qpoly2)

print(qpoly2.measure_polynomial())
QPolynomial.pc()
plt.show()
```

However, this appears to be getting very convoluted very fast. Is there a more elegant way of doing this conversion from classical to quantum? Any help would be highly appreciated!